# Java Double Array Error in String

Tags: java, arrays, string

I've been working on my java version of 2048, and I noticed an error in my program.
I assume everyone knows the game of 2048, so I won't explain the rules of the game. 
This is part of the code I had problems with, the display method. 
When I ran the program before adding the code that caused the problem, when the numbers got higher than 1 digit it gave an extra space to the number

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 32 0 0
0 2 0 0
```

and it was breaking the order of the board
so I was trying to fix it by adding 3, 2, or 1 space to 3, 2, and 1 digit numbers, respectively. 
The code for the method is below, please help me on the problem

-board is the main game board
-sd is the board only for this method, to help me on the spaces thing.

```
`public static void Display (int[][] board) {
   int x = 0;
   int y = 0;
   String sd[][] = new String [x][y];
  if (board[x][y] == 0 ||board[x][y] == 2 || board[x][y] == 4 || board[x][y] == 8) 
  { sd[0][y] = "board[0][y]" + "   ";
    y++; }
  if (board[x][y] == 0 ||board[x][y] == 2 || board[x][y] == 4 || board[x][y] == 8) 
  { sd[1][y] = "board[1][y]" + "   ";
    y++; }
  if (board[x][y] == 0 ||board[x][y] == 2 || board[x][y] == 4 || board[x][y] == 8) 
  { sd[2][y] = "board[2][y]" + "   ";
    y++; }
  if (board[x][y] == 0 ||board[x][y] == 2 || board[x][y] == 4 || board[x][y] == 8) 
  { sd[3][y] = "board[3][y]" + "   ";
    y++; }
System.out.println(sd[0][0] + " " + sd[0][1] + " " + sd[0][2] + " " + sd[0][3]); 
System.out.println(sd[1][0] + " " + sd[1][1] + " " + sd[1][2] + " " + sd[1][3]); 
System.out.println(sd[2][0] + " " + sd[2][1] + " " + sd[2][2] + " " + sd[2][3]); 
System.out.println(sd[3][0] + " " + sd[3][1] + " " + sd[3][2] + " " + sd[3][3]); 
System.out.println("--------");
}`
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. First, add the following two methods.

```
public int getMaxDigits() {
    int largestNumber = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < sd.length; i ++) {
        for(int j = 0; i < sd[0].length; j ++) {
            if(sd[i][j] > largestNumber) {
                largestNumber = sd[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    if(largestNumber > 999) {
        return 4;
    } else if(largestNumber > 99) {
        return 3;
    } else if(largestNumber > 9) {
        return 2;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

public String getValue(int x, int y, int maxDigits) {
    String value = "" + sd[x][y];

    while(value.length() != maxDigits) {
        value = " " + value;
    }

    return value;
}
```

Second, use the above two methods for printing. Like the following:

```
int maxDigits = getMaxDigits();
System.out.println(getValue(0, 0, maxDigits) + " " + getValue(0, 1, maxDigits) + " " + getValue(0, 2, maxDigits) + " " + getValue(0, 3, maxDigits));
```

P.S: I only did the first line.

Cheers!